# Post/Redirect/Get needed if you submit HTML fragments?

Tags: post-redirect-get, htmx

In the past I used the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern:

- the html for was submitted to the server via POST
- the server processed the data.
- if everything was ok, the server responsed with a http 302 (redirect
- the client redirected the page to the new location.

Is this still needed if you submit html fragments via [htmx](//htmx.org)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By and large **no**, you will not need to implement the PRG pattern.

Since htmx uses AJAX for most interactions, there is no request sitting in the browser history, and hitting refresh will not re-submit a POST (or DELETE or whatever).

That said, htmx trys to be *compatible* with the PRG pattern, and tries to update the URL if a redirect occurs by detecting the :

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/1d4c79490e491813ffb780354ec5df6d080b1e09/src/htmx.js#L2146

https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/1d4c79490e491813ffb780354ec5df6d080b1e09/src/htmx.js#L1851

If you do something like inline editing:

https://htmx.org/examples/click-to-edit/

The point becomes moot to a large extent, since you can have the edit UI at the same URL as the view URL.